# git clone :Corrupted MAC on input. (15760/787968)

Tags: git, fatal-error

when I use `git clone ${ssh://url}`

```
Corrupted MAC on input. (15760/787968)
enter code heressh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 192.168.0.240 port 29418: message authentication code incorrect
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

please help,I have no idea to solve this problem.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/994646/ssh-on-windows-corrupted-mac-on-input

Comment: I tested the ssh connection between my server and the server. Unlike the encryption method.And I tried to use scp to transfer small files successfully, but this problem persists when transferring large files. Thank you very much for your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Interesting: in your own answer, your screenshot has more output *before* the "Corrupted MAC" message. That's not something I have seen myself.

Comment: Yes,but I can't find something to help this problem,so I don't put it on my first question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i just intalled the ssh client and the problem solved.

```
apt-get install openssh-client
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I tested the ssh connection between my server and the server. Unlike the encryption method.